# Cant detect <form>.$error.mindate when <form>.$submitted

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to display an error message next to my datepicker if the user selects a to-date which is earlier than the selected from-date and opposite. This message should only show after the user clicks the submit button.

code:

```html
 <form name="form" ng-submit="ctrl.submit(form.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <md-datepicker name="fromDate" ng-model="ctrl.fromDate" ng-required="ctrl.toDate" md-max-date="ctrl.toDate"></md-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="form.fromDate.$error" ng-if="form.$submitted">
            <div ng-message="maxdate">From-date should be before to-date</div>
            <div ng-message="required">Fill in from-date</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <md-datepicker name="toDate" ng-model="ctrl.toDate" ng-required="ctrl.fromDate" md-min-date="ctrl.fromDate"></md-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="form.toDate.$error" ng-if="form.$submitted">
            <div ng-message="mindate">To-date should be after from-date</div>
            <div ng-message="required">Fill in from-date</div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

If i select fromDate 1/1/2 and toDate 1/1/1 then click submit, only the required error message is shown.
When inspecting the $error object, i see that the mindate/maxdate property is cleared when i click submit.

Im assuming this is due to md-datepicker not setting the model-value if the input-value is invalid according to rules like required, min, max etc.

Is it possible to get around this somehow?

Edit:
I think the problem is that angular is using the model-values to apply form errors after clicking submit instead of the input-values.

If I enter 1/1/2 as fromDate and click submit, then enter 1/1/1 as toDate, the correct error message will show.

Comment: You could try using [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) and set `{allowInvalid:true}`. No clue if it will fix your issue, just a guess.

Comment: Doesnt seems like allowInvalid does anything significant. Even though it did, I would be hesitant to use it as it would let the user set values like "abc123"(right?). Want to avoid handling that myself if i can.

Comment: yeah I think so. I just realised your datepickers don't have a model, you need to put `ng-model` on the `md-datepicker` elements

Comment: Yea, thanks. I'm working in an offline environment, so I have to manually copy the code over. Knew i would forget something:P

Comment: I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws6mr52h/2/) which is working fine, have you included `ngMessages` as a dependency in your app?

Comment: Yes. The `required` message pops up. Hmmm why does yours work and not mine. There is something wierd that happens. If i click submit fast enough after entering 1/1/1 in toDate, the `mindate` message shows. But if i wait a second or two, it doesnt when i click submit. This is driving me crazy :S

Comment: I honestly have no clue. I emailed myself my code and pasted it into a fiddle. It works there.

Comment: I give up for now. I commented out all code and html in my source code. The only difference between the fiddle and my source was a few bootstrap col wrappers and that I'm using ES6 syntax in my controller.

It still didn't work in my source code. I am unable to find out which part of the code resets the .$error object.

I found that the .$error object looks fine if i print it in a ng-click eventhandler from the button. But if i print it in the ng-submit handler, i get an .$error object only containing the required property.

Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when form loads the toDate and fromDate is blank!! Am i right??
if toDate and fromDate is blank then  please initialize the fromDate and toDate  with dayBeforeDate and currentDate respectively.

Like

**fromDate - 22March, 2017**

**toDate - 23March, 2017**

Comment: Yes, fromDate and toDate are both `undefined` at page load. Though initializing them wouldnt solve anything as md-datepicker wont allow me to change the model if it is an invalid value.

Comment: Acutally what happens when page loads toDate and fromDate validation goes in deadlock